# Does JDBI (3) have asymmetric support for beans?

Tags: java, sql, javabeans, jdbi

JDBI (3) has fantastic support for querying a bean:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY name")
@RegisterBeanMapper(User.class)
List<User> listUsers();
```

And, assuming the compiler is set to include parameter names, it also supports inserting beans:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO user(id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)")
void insertBean(@BindBean User user);
```

But apparently, when inserting a bean, it seems you need to enumerate all the bean fields, whereas for querying one, JDBI can figure them out on its own. Am I missing a solution, or does JDBI really have such different capabilities for querying/inserting ?

I would think that for both directions, the same information about the bean are needed, so I don't understand why for inserting, it can't figure out the fields on its own. Is there a reason for this difference, or am I just not seeing something obvious ?

Comment: I think this is not supported in JDBI but could be an interesting feature to add. You could also write a custom Binder that retrieves all the attributes from an object and adds the matching values to the SQLStatement.

Comment: This is rather outside Jdbi's charter. But Andre is correct that you could write a custom binding annotation to do this for you. http://jdbi.org/#_user_defined_annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jdbi is intended as a convenience layer to make it easier to work with SQL databases in Java.

Give Jdbi a SQL statement and some parameters, and the library will execute it and stuff the result (if any) into some object for you--the end.

Generating SQL is not a goal of Jdbi, although we do provide a few small conveniences through templating, e.g. `@BindList`.

From the [project documentation](http://jdbi.org/#_declarative_api) (emphasis added):

> Jdbi is not an ORM. There is no session cache, change tracking, "open session in view", or cajoling the library to understand your schema.
>
> Instead, Jdbi provides straightforward mapping between SQL and simple tabular data structures.
>
> *You bring your own SQL*, and Jdbi only runs the commands you tell it to—​the way God intended.